# Failed to install python 'google.colab' module

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I tried to install 'google.colab' module with pip, this problem came out:

```
  pandas\_libs/indexing.c(2812): error C2039: 
        "tp_print": 不是 "_typeobject" 的成员
  C:\Program Files\Python310\include\cpython/object.h(191): note: 参见“_typeobject”的声明       
  pandas\_libs/indexing.c(3199): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3 
  pandas\_libs/indexing.c(3215): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3 
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
      Running setup.py clean for pandas
  Failed to build pandas
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

It seems that the version of the google.colab is out of date, but I can't find a version other than 1.0.0 .
Maybe I can downgrade my python from version 3.10 to 3.8 to fix this problem, but thourgh that I can't use other new modules.

(updated 2023-6-11 4:00 UTC+8:00)
I checked the colab. The colab installed python 3.10.12 and google-colab 1.0.0. So I guess it's the problem of my MSVC complier or cpython, but I can't find out.

(updated 2023-6-11 5:43 UTC+8:00)
I checked the colab again and found the pandas 1.5.3, which is far newer then 0.42.0 that google-colab required.
Then I edited the `setup.py` of the google-colab 1.0.0 package, changed the requirements and manually installed the google-colab.
After I `import google.colab`, another error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\MyProjects\Python Projects\chatai\colabio.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google import colab
File "C:\Users\ImeI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\google\colab\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from google.colab import _system_commands
File "C:\Users\ImeI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\google\colab\_system_commands.py", line 24, in <module>        
    import pty
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\pty.py", line 12, in <module>
    import tty
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tty.py", line 5, in <module>
    from termios import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'
```

I searched the problem, and finally found out that, the 'google-colab' module just doesn't support Windows.
**** ***.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install an older version of the module:

```
pip install pandas==1.3.4
```

(this up here is an example) or make a VM (Virtual Machine) that uses Python 3.8.

Comment: Doesn't work. google-colab needs `pandas~=0.24.0`.

Comment: How can I use python3.10 and python3.8 at the same time?